# On the characterization of a subspace (proof of a lemma).

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces

This is a very well know lemma

[image]

I am trying to prove this. I have some doubts on proving that $W$ has the identity element of addition, i.e., that there exists an element  $0 \in W$ s.t. $\forall w \in W $ we have $ \ w + 0 = w.$
Could I see a quick proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $w\in W$ ($W$ is nonempty). Thus $0_V=0\cdot w + 0\cdot w\in W$ (Take $v=w$ and $\alpha=\beta=0$ in 1.11).

Note, that $W$ is a subset of $V$. Thus the addition in $W$ is the same as in $V$. So $0_V$ is the neutral element of $W$. You only need to prove, that $0_V \in W$.